# string param in hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec does not resolve

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-github-plugin

Why is it that one job doesn't resolve param used in hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec while another does?   Is BRANCH_NAME special in some way and BACKEND_BRANCH not?

**Good Job**

```
      <parameterDefinitions>
    <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
      <name>BRANCH_NAME</name>
      <description>The branch to deploy from.</description>
      <defaultValue>mybranch</defaultValue>
    </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
    <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
  ....
  <branches>
    <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
      <name>*/${BRANCH_NAME}</name>
    </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
  </branches>
```

**Failing Job**

```
  <parameterDefinitions>
    ...
    <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
      <name>BACKEND_BRANCH</name>
      <description>Branch for build deployed to environment</description>
    </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
  ...
  <branches>
    <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
      <name>*/${BACKEND_BRANCH}</name>
    </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
  </branches>
```

**Error**

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command
"/usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress origin 
+refs/heads/${BACKEND_BRANCH}:refs/remotes/origin/${BACKEND_BRANCH} -
-prune" returned 
...
stderr: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/${BACKEND_BRANCH}
```

Comment: ${branch} works for me in Jenkins 2.375.2 (and lots of plugins, all installed more than a year ago), but it does not work in Jenkins 2.303.1